# Image of the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|>r\}$ by the complex exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the image of the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|>r\}$ by the complex exponential function $x+iy \rightarrow e^x(\cos(y) + i \sin(y))$.

Previously, I found that the image of horizontal lines are half lines and that the image of horizontal lines are circumferences.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $e^x(cos(y)+isin(y))=e^x (e^(iy))=e^z$? If so, the modulos (radius) becomes r=e^x and the argument (angle) becomes y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s call your set $S$. The image of $S$ does not contain the origin; on the other hand, the image of $S$ contains the image of the horizontal strip $r\le y\le r+2\pi i$, which is all of the punctured plane. So $\exp S$ is the complex plane punctured at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Define the set $A:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>r\}=\{x+iy:x,y\in\mathbb{R}\,\wedge\,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>r\}\subset\mathbb{C}$. From what I understand, $r$ is some real number greater than zero, and you have a map
\begin{align*}
\phi:A&\longrightarrow\mathbb{R} \\
x+iy&\longmapsto e^x(\cos(y)+\sin(y))
\end{align*}
of which you want to know the image, $\mathrm{im}(\phi)$. Let $n_r\ge 1$ be the unique integer such that $n-1<r\le n$.

Clearly $\mathrm{im}(\phi)\subset\mathbb{R}$. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$. If $a=0$, then $r-i\frac{\pi}{4}\in A$ is such that $\phi(r-i\frac{\pi}{4})=0$, so $0\in\mathrm{im}(\phi)$. If $a<0$, then $\ln(-a)+in_r\frac{3\pi}{2}\in A$ is such that $\phi(\ln(-a)+in_r\frac{3\pi}{2})=a$. If $a>0$, then $\ln(a)+in_r\frac{3\pi}{2}\in A$ is such that $\phi(\ln(a)+in_r\frac{3\pi}{2})=a$, so $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathrm{im}(\phi)$ and thus $\mathrm{im}(\phi)=\mathbb{R}$.

In the more probable case that you meant what @Trouble mentioned, i.e. the map
\begin{align*}
\psi:A&\longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \\
x+iy&\longmapsto e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y)),
\end{align*}
then it is clear that $\phi$ maps an element $z\in A$ to a complex number of norm $e^x$ and angle $y$. Then if $x=0$ it must hold that $|y|>r$, so any angle can be achieved. However the norm will always be greater than zero since $e^x>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathrm{im}(\phi)=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.